# PHP PDO Invalid parameter number. Although all params are set

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I am creating a PHP application which will compile a list of computers.
This list will be generated dynamically. Thus I am tring to insert data into a MYSQL database. The code below is not designed to give a response to the user unless an error occurs.
 I am getting the error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\netman\connect.php on line 39

My code is:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE bots SET compName=':compName', username=':username',
             ramTotal=':ram', vendor=':vendor', IP=':IP', last=NOW() WHERE machineID = :machID");
            $stmt->execute([
                "machID" => $_GET['machineID'],
                "compName" => $_GET['compName'],
                "username" => $_GET['user'],
                "vendor" => $_GET['vendor'],
                "ram" => $_GET['memory'],
                "IP" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            ]);
```

Comment: You don't put bind variable values in quotes `compName=:compName`

Comment: @RaymondNijland, should be

Answer (score 0):

Silly Mistake I made:

> You don't put bind variable values in quotes compName=:compName – @RaymondNijland

New Code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE bots SET compName=:compName, username=:username,
             ramTotal=:ram, vendor=:vendor, IP=:IP, last=NOW() WHERE machineID = :machID");
            $stmt->execute([
                "machID" => $_GET['machineID'],
                "compName" => $_GET['compName'],
                "username" => $_GET['user'],
                "vendor" => $_GET['vendor'],
                "ram" => $_GET['memory'],
                "IP" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            ]);
```

Thank You